# Using "Je vais,on va, ... etc." to mean "Let's" ?

Tags: sens, traduction, vocabulaire, anglais, usage

In some texts, it seems to me using "Sujet + aller" can mean "Let me, let's" instead of "going to". Check those below for example:

"Merci d’être avec moi aujourd’hui, je suis très content que vous écoutiez ce podcast. Et pour commencer, **je vais vous présenter** l’idée de ce podcast. Alors, le Cottongue podcast, qu’est-ce que c’est ? C’est tout simplement pour les gens qui apprennent le français et qui ne trouvent pas de choses intéressantes à écouter."

"En général, on pense que la plupart de nos décisions sont rationnelles. On analyse la situation, les conditions, les résultats possibles, et on prend la meilleure décision possible, la plus rationnelle. Mais êtes-vous vraiment sûrs d’être si rationnels que ça ? **On va faire** une petite expérience pour le vérifier. Imaginez que vous êtes dans le métro, vous allez au travail. À côté de vous, il y a un homme très élégant qui porte un costume et une cravate. À votre avis, est-ce que ce monsieur a un doctorat ou bien est-ce qu’il n’a pas fait d’études ?"

"J’espère que tout va bien chez vous et que vous profitez du printemps ! Si vous n’avez pas écouté les épisodes précédents, **je vais vous expliquer** pourquoi je fais ce podcast."

I translated all of these as "Let me" or "let's". But some people say that in order that one can translate them as "let.." there must be imperative case. (e.g. Let's do = Faisons, not "On va faire"). So my translations are wrong.

My question is if I want to say "Let's ..." and I do use "On va..." or "Je vais..." for "let me", would I be understood as "We are going to..." or "I am going to..." ?

Hopefully, you got what I mean. I am so confused. I do not want to get misunderstood.

Thank you so much.

Comment: I’m confused by your question. “On va” means “We are going to” in English, but sometimes “Let’s” also means “We are going to” in English. Unless this is a translation exercise for a language class, I don’t see why you shouldn’t translate the meaning rather than translating word-for-word.

Comment: @Ville 1st person plural imperative is uncommon in modern colloquial French. The meaning can be the same as "on va ..." but it's a matter of speech register. You would use "faisons/allons/pensons..." in a written essay but not really when chatting with your friends.